# Android studio: How to have different run configurations for every build variant

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I have an Android project in Android-studio with different build variants for both x86 and ARM.

I was wondering if there is a way to create different "run/debug configurations" for each build variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change build command for your build configurations by modifying Gradle-aware Make command:

[image: Change Run Configuration]

but then you still have to change build variant in Build Variants tool window to deploy correct APK to your device.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create different configurations.

Read this document: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: The questions is not if you can have different configurations, It's if you can configure the Android-studio "run/build configuration" to point at an specific build variant.