# Change Build Variant directly in Run Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build-flavors, build-variant

Considering this screen :

[image: scrnsht]

Today, when I want to change the build variant of my app, I click on menu #1 and switch to the one I want.

The thing I want to do, is creating multiple run configurations (click #2), for each of my useful variants. Studio automatically create builds/flavors combinaison I don't need in the variants menu.

I assume that it will have something to do with the "Before lanch" menu on the bottom of the screen, but can't figure out exactly which Gradle rule am I suppose to add to select the good variants.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find anything after all these years?

Comment: Does this other question/answer help(maybe it's even a duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045716/android-studio-how-to-have-different-run-configurations-for-every-build-variant