# Set Build Variant from Run Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

Is there a way for a Run Configuration in Android Studio or IntelliJ to change the build variant?

I have `release` and `debug` with `local` and `azure` flavors. I've made a run configuration for each combination, for example AzureDebug. What it does is basically calling the command `gradlew installAzureDebug`. If, though, the variant AzureRelease is selected Android Studio will still open the AzureRelease version of the app in the emulator.

I searched for an answer, but all I could find was this [Change Build Variant directly in Run Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49127748/2115403) with no answer yet.

Maybe my approach is completely wrong and there's a simpler way?